# MKSnapshotter sizing issues inside UITableViewCell using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Example of this issue can be found at https://github.com/SRowley90/MKMapSnapshotterExample

I have an issue where I need to display a map snapshot inside a table cell. I have an image view with fixed height inside a containing view inside a UIStackView, so I can have larger margins than the stack view offers in spacing (this is more not relevant to the issue though).

My issue is that an MKSnapshotter requires the size to be given of the view before the cell has decided what it's width is. The `setup()` method is called on the cell which creates the `MKSnapshotter.Options` with the size it has at the time, which comes directly from the nib file for the cell.

```
let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
options.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: distanceInMeters, longitudinalMeters: distanceInMeters)
options.size = self.mapSnapshotImageView.bounds.size
```

The MKSnapshotter gets the image and sets this in the UIImageView and then the cell lays out the views according to the Autolayout properties, so the image brought back is no longer the right size for the view. In the example I do a poor job at cacheing this image so I can demonstrate better.

I need the image brought back to use the full width of the ImageView that displays it but I'm not sure how to do this.

[image]